# Using db.Find when have composite Primary keys and only want to use one

Tags: c#, mysql, asp.net-mvc, entity-framework, find

I have a table called accounts which is as below:

```
[Key]
public int SiteID { get; set; }
[Key]
public long AccountID { get; set; }
public string Name { get; set; }
public string AccountCode { get; set; }
public string AccountType { get; set; }
```

I am trying to use Entity Framework to display the information in the table where SiteID = 999999.
I am attempting to use a db.Find method to display the list of 'accounts' where siteID = 999999.

My current code:
index.cshtml

```
@Html.ActionLink("Mapping","ConfigureMapping", new { id = item.SiteID })
```

Controller

```
 Account account = SiteDatabase.Accounts.Find(id);
 if (account == null)
 {
     return HttpNotFound();
 }
 return View(account);
```

But this complains about only receiving 1 out of 2 primary keys:
"The number of primary key values passed must match number of primary key values defined on the entity."

How do i do this???

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `Find` method returns a single object, not a collection. If you want all the records with SiteID=999999, Use the `Where` method to get a filtered list.

For example,

```
List<Account> accountList = SiteDatabase.Accounts.Where(a=>a.SiteID==id).ToList();
```

where `id` has the value `999999` or some other valid site id value

If you want a single item, you can use the `FirstOrDefault` as an alternate option of `Find`

```
Account account = SiteDatabase.Accounts.FirstOrDefault(a=>a.SiteID==id);
```

Keep in mind that, **this will return the first match**. So if you have 2 records with same `SiteID` value (but different `AccountID`), it will just return the first one , that might not be the one you are looking for. So i suggest you get the record based on the unique key value (unique key value combinations). Perhaps you can pass the account id as well from ui and use that (along with siteId) for getting the single -correct object as needed.

Comment: progress. i now get past that error but now getting.

The model item passed into the dictionary is of type 'System.Collections.Generic.List`1[MultiTenantWebApp.Models.Account]', but this dictionary requires a model item of type 'System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable`1[Xero.Api.Core.Model.Account]'.'

I have tried .AsEnumerable() but no luck

Comment: That is because you are passing down a list of `MultiTenantWebApp.Models.Account` objects, but it takes a list of `Xero.Api.Core.Model.Account` objects

Comment: @JoshFletcher Looks like you have 2 different places where you have `Account` class defined.  Update your view to use the same type as of the one which your action method is returning.

Answer (score 0):

You need to supply the other key to the find as well, first add it to the actionlink:

```
@Html.ActionLink("Mapping","ConfigureMapping", new { id = item.SiteID, accountID = item.AccountID })
```

Add the parameter to your controller and then use it in the find as such:

```
Account account = SiteDatabase.Accounts.Find(id, accountID);
```

Comment: this will not work as one siteID can have many accountID's. This will only pass one accountID so the full list of multiple accounts will not be displayed